# Overloaded Prefix/Postfix Compiler Optimization

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, compiler-optimization

Is compiler allowed to optimize an overloaded postfix operator and replace it with prefix operator? (provided that compiler *knows* what overloaded function does)

For example, in the following code, most compilers treat `i++` as `++i` and generate same assembly.

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    printf("*");
```

Then, could same apply for the following code?

```
class Integer {
    int data;
    Integer& operator++() { ++data; return *this; }
    Integer operator++(int) { Integer ret = *(this); ++(*this); return ret; }
    // And more overloads...
};

for(Integer i=0; i<5; i++)
    printf("*");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An optimiser is allowed to do *anything* so long as it doesn't change the behaviour of the code. (This known as [the "as-if" rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule).)

So yes, in your first snippet `++i` and `i++` will be optimised to the same thing on most compilers. (Although that was once not the case, which is why old cats like me still use `++i` in a `for`loop.).

In your second case, the compiler could optimise away the value copy as part of an extension of named return value optimisation (NRVO), assuming the returned result is not used.